Textbox editing problem in jQuery & FabricJS
I want to open an image in a canvas to add text on it. However the textbox is not allowing editing.


$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var imgElement = new Image();
  var currentImageId;
  var currentTool = '';

  // Event listener for clicking "Edit" link
  $('.edit-image-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the image ID and source from the clicked link
    var imageId = $(this).data('image-id');
    var imageSrc = $(this).data('image-src');
    currentImageId = imageId;

    // Load the image into the canvas
    imgElement.src = imageSrc;
    imgElement.onload = function() {
      canvas.clear();
      var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        selectable: false,
        evented: false
      });

      // Scale the image to fit the canvas while maintaining aspect ratio
      var scaleFactor = Math.min(canvas.width / imgElement.width, canvas.height / imgElement.height);
      imgInstance.scale(scaleFactor);

      canvas.add(imgInstance);
      canvas.centerObject(imgInstance);
      canvas.renderAll();
    };

    // Show the modal
    $('#imageEditorModal').modal('show');
  });

  // Text tool activation
  $('#text-tool').on('click', function() {
    currentTool = 'text';
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    canvas.selection = true;

    // Remove any previous event handlers to avoid multiple bindings
    canvas.off('mouse:down');

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
      if (currentTool !== 'text') return;

      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
      var text = new fabric.IText('Sample Text', {
        left: pointer.x,
        top: pointer.y,
        fill: '#FF0000',
        fontSize: 20,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true
      });

      canvas.add(text);
      canvas.setActiveObject(text);
      text.enterEditing();
      text.selectAll();
      currentTool = ''; // reset tool to avoid creating multiple text objects

      // Set focus to the hidden textarea
      text.hiddenTextarea.focus();

      // Remove mouse:down event listener to prevent multiple text object creation
      canvas.off('mouse:down');
    });
  });

  $('#reset-image').on('click', function() {
    imgElement.src = imgElement.src; // Reload the original image
  });

  // Ensure hiddenTextarea is focused when editing text
  canvas.on('text:changed', function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.type === 'i-text') {
      e.target.enterEditing();
      e.target.hiddenTextarea.focus();
    }
  });

  canvas.on('selection:created', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.type === 'i-text') {
      e.target.enterEditing();
      e.target.hiddenTextarea.focus();
    }
  });

  canvas.on('selection:updated', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.type === 'i-text') {
      e.target.enterEditing();
      e.target.hiddenTextarea.focus();
    }
  });

  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (canvas.getActiveObject() && canvas.getActiveObject().isEditing) {
      canvas.getActiveObject().hiddenTextarea.focus();
    }
  });
});
.thumbnail {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tools {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h2 class="mt-5">Images</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="m-1 thumbnail rounded-3 border-1" width="70px" src="images/image1.jpg" />
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="edit-image-link" data-image-id="1" data-image-src="images/image1.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageEditorModal">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="imageEditorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="imageEditorModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="imageEditorModalLabel">Image Editor</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
        <div class="tools mt-3">
          <button id="text-tool">Text</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="reset-image">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



